# Height of right-side border

Tags: html, css

I need make same height of border for every element.
here is the screen of problem http://postimg.org/image/40lg6rynf/

**HTML**

```
     <div class="row projekty">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="marquee">
          <?php
              echo '<div class="projekt">';
              echo '<p>' . $row['item_name'] . '</p>';
              echo $row['item_text'];
              echo '<a href="' . $row['item_url'] . '">více informací zde...</a>';
              echo '</div>';
          ?>

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.projekty {
    background-color: #d8d8d7;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.projekt {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    background:url("../img/border_line.png") bottom right no-repeat;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is give your .projekt a fixed height.

```
height: 300px;
```

I understand what you are accomplishing here but if I were you, I'd use border-right: 1px solid #cdcdcd; then give your item a margin horzontally, and to eliminate the last instance of a border, just use last:child and give it a border:none

next time a workable fiddle may be more suitable than a picture ;)